# Deform cylinder face into triangle

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms, surface-deform

I have a disc with a triangular hole in it.

I want the things that fall into the triangle hole to go into a smaller cylinder that goes below, like a funnel.

Is there a way I can deform the small cylinder so the triangular hole of the bigger cylinder is its new opening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try boolean modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable [`LoopTools`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkof4.png) via menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > LoopTools*

[image]

Start with a plane and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to subdivide it 3 times and apply it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Visual Geometry to Mesh*

[image]

Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and select all with <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> LoopTools > Circle*. And then model it into a nice perfect quad topology pie as shown in such a way that you will end up with 16 vertices in the triangular opening.

[image]

Add a cylinder into the same object and remove the top face of it. In this case I have 16 vertices for the triangle and 16 vertices for the cylindrical top. Then select the edge loop of the triangle and the edge loop of the cylindrical top.

[image]

Then simply go to menu *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops* and increase the *Number of Cuts* as needed.

[image]

Here's the final model with a Solidify Modifier and a Subdivision Surface Modifier.

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!